# Smooth Scroll to Anchor tag stops much above the anchor tag

Tags: jquery, anchor, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to get smooth scrolling functionality on my website. Currently this is the problem I am facing. When I redirect to another page with an anchor tag in the URL reference, the scrolling stops much before the anchor tag, if the tag is preceded by an image.

For example:

try going from `home -> About Us # Theory of Change`. This works as intended. Now suppose I move from `home -> About Us # Our Team` you will notice a slight offset. This is a lot more pronounced, if you were to try and go from `home -> Our Work # Pilot Study` the page would stop almost, `300 - 400 px` above the section where the anchor tag is contained. The scrolling works just fine to those places if done withing the page itself i.e., from `About Us -> #Our Team` you will see the scrolling work just fine.

[URL to website](http://www.scholowiz.com/)

Comment: Hmm, I noticed on chrome too sometimes. But mostly the issue is on firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be executing on `domready`. I suspect the issue is caused by images not being fully loaded when the smooth scroll code is executed.

I suggest trying to trigger the smooth scroll code on `load`, instead of on `domready`.